# loading vertex and edge as dataFrame for graphFrame

Tags: java, json, dataframe, graphframes

I have two json file. And there is "friend" relation between this two json files. I ant to create vertex and edge using this two json files. After that I will create graphFrame. Here I am using java and spark. But can't understand how can I do that. Pleasee help!!